# extract the first part of each string in a data frame in r

Tags: r

I have a data frame `M`. I would like to extract the first part of each string separated by `":"`. I used `strsplit` but the result is a large character not a data frame. Could someone please help with this?

```
M <- read.table(text=
"1/1:205,54,0:18:0:57 1/1:141,39,0:13:0:42   0/0:0,54,255:18:0:45 1/1:174,48,0:16:0:51 0/0:0,84,255:28:0:75 
 0/0:0,78,255:26:0:99 0/0:0,63,255:21:0:86   0/0:0,45,255:15:0:68 0/0:0,48,255:16:0:71 0/0:0,132,255:44:0:99
 0/0:0,78,255:26:0:89 0/0:0,78,255:26:0:89   0/0:0,36,255:12:0:47 0/0:0,33,255:11:0:44 0/0:0,108,255:36:0:99
 0/0:0,75,255:25:0:99 0/0:0,54,255:18:0:78   0/0:0,69,255:23:0:93 0/0:0,33,255:11:0:57 0/0:0,96,255:32:0:99 
 0/0:0,60,75:21:0:74  0/0:0,51,84:17:0:65    0/0:0,48,64:17:0:62  0/0:0,42,65:15:0:56  0/0:0,84,99:28:0:98 ",
head=F, stringsAsFactors=F)
S <- sapply(strsplit(M, ":"), "[", 1)
```

Comment: Please provide your expected output

Comment: I need "0/0", or "1/1" ..

Comment: `sapply(M, function(x) sapply(strsplit(as.character(x), ':'),'[',1))`

Comment: `lapply(M, function(x) gsub(":.*","",x))`

Comment: You should do an SO search on: `[r] extract the first part of each string`. I get 15 hits. One of those is almost surely a duplicate.

Comment: Also related: [Splitting a dataframe string column into multiple different columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18641951/splitting-a-dataframe-string-column-into-multiple-different-columns) and e.g. `splitstackshape::cSplit`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It may not be best to use `strsplit` as we are only interested in a substring.  Assuming that the OP is interested in understanding how `strsplit` can be used for this example dataset, a modification of the OP's code would be to use a nested `lapply/sapply` loop.

```
 M[] <- lapply(M, function(x) sapply(strsplit(as.character(x), ':'),'[',1))
 M
 #   V1  V2  V3  V4  V5
 #1 1/1 1/1 0/0 1/1 0/0
 #2 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0
 #3 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0
 #4 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0
 #5 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0
```

Or as the columns are all similar, we can `unlist`, use `strsplit` and assign the original dataset with the output so that we can keep the original structure intact for the output we got.

```
  M[] <- sapply(strsplit(unlist(M), ':'),'[',1)
```

Or a faster option would be using `stri_extract_first` from `stringi` to extract the the characters that are not `:`.

```
  library(stringi)
  M[] <- stri_extract_first(unlist(M), regex='[^:]+')
```

Comment: option1 seems need long time. option2: gave a short time but the result data str is still a large character not the dataframe or matrix

Comment: @user3354212  The result will be a vector.  But when you assign it to `M[] <-...` it will be a data.frame with the original structure intact

Comment: I was wrong comment with the data str that I looked a different data. I like option 3, that only used 8.14 seconds, option2 used 67.73 sec. The answer 3 From Richard Scriven used 155.05 sec for my real data. Thanks.

Comment: @user3354212  Did you meant the option 1 used `155.05 sec`.   It makes sense as we are using a nested loop there.  `stringi` methods should be very fast (option 3)

Comment: Option1 is lapply(M, function(x) sapply(strsplit(as.character(x), ':'),'[',1))

Comment: @user3354212  Yes, I would expect that to be slower as it involves nested loops.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
dplyr::mutate_each(M, funs(sub("(.*?)(:.*)", "\\1" , .)))
```

Which gives:

```
#   V1  V2  V3  V4  V5
#1 1/1 1/1 0/0 1/1 0/0
#2 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0
#3 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0
#4 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0
#5 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0
```

Comment: there is an error with your code, > dplyr::mutate_each(M, funs(sub("(.*?)(:.*)", "\\1" , .)))
Error in UseMethod("tbl_vars") : 
  no applicable method for 'tbl_vars' applied to an object of class "c('matrix', 'character')"

Comment: What does `class(M)` returns ? From your question, I assumed it was a `data.frame`

Comment: M is a large matrix. I tested M as data frame. it works. it used 20.49 sec for my real data.  pretty good!

Answer (score 4):

You can use `sub()`

```
M[] <- lapply(M, sub, pattern = ":.*", replacement = "")
M
#    V1  V2  V3  V4  V5
# 1 1/1 1/1 0/0 1/1 0/0
# 2 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0
# 3 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0
# 4 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0
# 5 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0
```

The above will overwrite the original `M` data.  If you do not wish to overwrite `M`, assign it to a new variable name first or just use `as.data.frame()` around `lapply()`

```
as.data.frame(lapply(M, sub, pattern = ":.*", replacement = ""))
```