# splitting contents of dataframe column into different columns based on values

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to split the following dataframe column into 3 columns depending on what the contents are. I tried using dplyr and mutate because I wanted to learn them better, but any suggestions would be welcome.

```
exampledf<-data.frame(c("Argentina","2005/12","2005/11","Bolivia","2006/12"),stringsAsFactors=F)
mutate(exampledf,month=strsplit(exampledf[,1],"/")[1],month=strsplit(exampledf[,1],"/")[2])
```

My Goal:

```
Year     Month    Country
2005     12       Argentina
2005     11       Argentina
2006     12       Bolivia
```

This is very close to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18641951/splitting-a-dataframe-string-column-into-multiple-different-columns) SO post, but it doesnt address my repeating country issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We create a logical index for rows that have no numbers ('i1'), get the cumulative sum of that, `split` the dataset with that grouping index, extract the 'year', 'month' with (`sub`), and the 'Country' as the first element, create a `data.frame`, and `rbind` the `list` contents.

```
 i1 <- grepl('^[^0-9]+$', exampledf$Col1)
 lst <- lapply(split(exampledf, cumsum(i1)), function(x) 
   data.frame(year= as.numeric(sub('\\/.*', '',   x[-1,1])), 
              month = as.numeric(sub('.*\\/', '', x[-1,1])),
              Country = x[1,1] ) )
 res <- do.call(rbind, lst)
 row.names(res) <- NULL

 res
 # year month   Country
 #1 2005    12 Argentina
 #2 2005    11 Argentina
 #3 2006    12   Bolivia
```

---

Or using `data.table`, we convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(exampledf)`), grouped by the `cumsum` of the index (from above), we split ( `tstrsplit`) on the 'Col1' (removing the first element) with delimiter (`/`).  We get two columns out of that. Then, concatenate the first element to create three columns and change the column names with `setnames`.  If we don't need the grouping variable, it can be assigned (`:=`) to NULL.

```
library(data.table)
res1 <- setDT(exampledf)[, c(tstrsplit(Col1[-1], 
        '/'),Country = Col1[1L]), .(i2=cumsum(i1))][,i2:= NULL][]
setnames(res1, 1:2, c('year', 'month'))
```

#### data

```
 exampledf<-data.frame(Col1=c("Argentina","2005/12","2005/11",
          "Bolivia","2006/12"),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining that data.table code (like how people sometimes explain regex). I'd like to understand what's happening there.

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen  Sure, thanks for the comment.  I was away.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate it. So, just to clarifty, i1 and i2 came from `tstrsplit`? Also, is there any particular reason you chose `setDT` over just wrapping it in `data.table`?

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen The `i1` came from `i1 <- grepl('^[^0-9]+$', exampledf$Col1)`, and I did the `cumsum` and named it as `i2`, But, it could be done within the `data.table`, i.e.  `..., .(i2 = cumsum(grepl('^[^0-9]+$', Col1))]` .  Regarding the second question, it is just a preference (slightly faster though).  If you use `as.data.table`, the original object will not be changed to `data.table`, but here it changes.  However, we can also use `setDF(res1)`, if we need to convert back to `data.frame` or `setDF(exampledf)`

Answer (score 4):

My approach is not very elegant but tries to clean the data step by step...

```
edf<-data.frame(c("Argentina","2005/12","2005/11","Bolivia","2006/12"),
                stringsAsFactors=F)

names(edf) <- "x"  # just to give a concise name

# flag if the row shows the month or not
edf$isMonth <- (regexpr("^[0-9]+/[0-9]+$", edf$x) > 0)

# expand the country 
# (i.e. if the row is month, reuse the country from the previous row)
edf$country <- edf$x
for (i in seq(2, nrow(edf))) {
  if (edf$isMonth[i]) {
    edf$country[i] <- edf$country[i-1]
  }
}

# now only the rows with month are relevant
edf <- edf[edf$isMonth,]
```

This gets you:

```
     x isMonth   country
2005/12    TRUE Argentina
2005/11    TRUE Argentina
2006/12    TRUE   Bolivia
```

Now, the remaining task is to split your year-month variable into year and month.  In your example code `strsplit` fails because the function `strsplit` returns a list, and `mutate` function conducts vectorized operation rather than element-wise.

In this particular case I find `stringr::str_match` to be useful.

```
library(stringr)
matched <- str_match(edf$x, "([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)")
edf$year <- matched[, 2]
edf$month <- matched[, 3]
```

The result is:

```
      x isMonth   country year month    
2005/12    TRUE Argentina 2005    12
2005/11    TRUE Argentina 2005    11
2006/12    TRUE   Bolivia 2006    12
```

Answer (score 3):

An Alternative strategy. It's not concise, but it's easy to follow.

```
library(tidyr)
df <-data.frame(Country = c("Argentina","2005/12","2005/11","Bolivia","2006/12"),stringsAsFactors=F)
df$dates[grep("[0-9]",df$Country)] <- df$Country[grep("[0-9]",df$Country)]
df$Country[grep("[0-9]",df$Country)] <- NA

replace_with <- 1
for(i in 1:length(df$Country)) {
  if(!is.na(df$Country[i])) {
    replace_with <- df$Country[i]
    next
  } else {
    x[i] <- replace_with
  }
}
df$Country <- x
df <- separate(df, dates, c("Year", "Month"), "/")
df <- na.omit(df)
df
    Country Year Month
2 Argentina 2005    12
3 Argentina 2005    11
5   Bolivia 2006    12
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's another option. You can use [`read.mtable` from my "SOfun" package](https://github.com/mrdwab/SOfun/blob/master/R/read.mtable.R) along with `cSplit` from "splitstackshape" and `rbindlist` from "data.table".

Assuming you have loaded at least the `read.mtable` function (in case you don't want to install the package) the approach would be:

```
library(SOfun)
library(splitstackshape)

rbindlist(lapply(read.mtable(textConnection(exampledf[[1]]), "[a-z]"), 
                 cSplit, "V1", "/"), idcol = TRUE)
#          .id V1_1 V1_2
# 1: Argentina 2005   12
# 2: Argentina 2005   11
# 3:   Bolivia 2006   12
```

Alternatively, you can split the data with `read.mtable` itself (though I suspect that `cSplit` might be faster). Thus, the approach would be:

```
# library(SOfun)
# library(data.table)
rbindlist(read.mtable(textConnection(exampledf[[1]]), "[a-z]", 
                      sep = "/", col.names = c("Year", "Month")), idcol = TRUE)
#          .id Year Month
# 1: Argentina 2005    12
# 2: Argentina 2005    11
# 3:   Bolivia 2006    12
```

With that approach, you have the added advantage of naming the columns in the process.