# grep part of rowname and save in new column

Tags: r

I have a data frame with rownames that contains space separated strings. I would like to grep the last 5 part of the rowname and save it in a new column.

```
hsa-let-7f-5p TGAGGTAGTAGATTGTATAAA 0 I-AA 0 gtt
```

To get part one I do this:

```
read.table(text=rownames(df))$V1
```

What I want:

```
TGAGGTAGTAGATTGTATAAA 0 I-AA 0 gtt
```

Comment: Relevant posts: [Splitting a dataframe string column into multiple different columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18641951), [Split a column of a data frame to multiple columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350440).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can either split the string with `strsplit`, get the last 5 elements with `tail` and `paste` it together

```
 paste(tail(strsplit(str1, "\\s+")[[1]],5), collapse=" ")
 #[1] "TGAGGTAGTAGATTGTATAAA 0 I-AA 0 gtt"
```

If we have multiple elements, we loop through the `list` (output from `strsplit`) and do the same as above.

```
 sapply(strsplit(rep(str1,2), " "), function(x) paste(tail(x, 5), collapse=" "))
 #[1] "TGAGGTAGTAGATTGTATAAA 0 I-AA 0 gtt" "TGAGGTAGTAGATTGTATAAA 0 I-AA 0 gtt"
```

Or use `str_extract`

```
 library(stringr)
 str_extract(str1, "(\\S+\\s+){4}\\S+$")
 #[1] "TGAGGTAGTAGATTGTATAAA 0 I-AA 0 gtt"
```

Part of the same pattern can be used in `sub` from `base R`

```
sub(".*\\s+((\\S+\\s+){4})(\\S+)$", "\\1\\3", str1)
#[1] "TGAGGTAGTAGATTGTATAAA 0 I-AA 0 gtt"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "hsa-let-7f-5p TGAGGTAGTAGATTGTATAAA 0 I-AA 0 gtt"
```

Comment: ahh...this makes more sense

Comment: Does it take all input rows? It seems to only work in the first row.

Comment: @user2300940 : Yes. Those will work except for the first one.

Answer (score 3):

We can use `word` from `stringr`,

```
library(stringr)
paste(word(x, -5:-1), collapse = ' ')
#[1] "TGAGGTAGTAGATTGTATAAA 0 I-AA 0 gtt"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this

```
library(stringr)
library(stringi)
word(V1,stri_count(V1,regex="\\S+")-4,stri_count(V1,regex="\\S+"))
```

***Data***

```
V1<-"hsa-let-7f-5p TGAGGTAGTAGATTGTATAAA 0 I-AA 0 gtt"
```