# Text analysis within data frame in r

Tags: r, text-analysis

I am working on Google Store metadata and have it as a data frame. Per each app there is information about the requested permissions within a single cell, as a long text, for example:

> READ SENSITIVE LOG DATA|RETRIEVE RUNNING APPS|FIND ACCOUNTS ON THE DEVICE|READ YOUR OWN CONTACT CARD|READ YOUR CONTACTS|

I want to separate the text between the "|" character into different cells (columns), so I can analyze existing permissions. I did not analyze text with R before. I tried using strings functions, however, when looking at the info within the cell, it is not recognized as a string.

Any suggestions, directions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:
Example string -

```
strin1 <- "READ SENSITIVE LOG DATA|RETRIEVE RUNNING APPS|FIND ACCOUNTS ON THE DEVICE|READ YOUR OWN CONTACT CARD|READ YOUR CONTACTS|"

read.table(text = strin1, sep ='|', colClasses = character)
```

Does the trick.

A better solution is using `tidyr` package in this answer: [Splitting a dataframe string column into multiple different columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18641951/splitting-a-dataframe-string-column-into-multiple-different-columns/18642168#18642168)

Comment: Thanks! the cSplit function from 'splitstackshape' package worked :)