# Convert a PostgreSQL integer[] array to a numeric list in R

Tags: arrays, r, postgresql, type-conversion

I am storing the result of a PostgreSQL query as a `data.frame` in R.  One of the "columns" is an `integer[]` array type.  In R, this is imported as a character string by the `RPostgreSQL` package.

How do I convert the character string type into a numeric list type column (or as separate numeric columns) in my `data.frame`?

#### connect and get data

```
require(RPostgreSQL)
drv = dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
con = dbConnect(drv, host = ..., post =..., dbname =..., user=..., password=...)
df = dbGetQuery(con, query_string)
dbDisconnect(con)
```

#### minimum working example

```
library(dplyr)
# randomized arrays of 10 numbers
set.seed(10)
df = data.frame(id = c(1:10)) %>%
  mutate(arrcol = lapply(id, function(X) sample(1:99, 10, replace=T)),
         arrcol = gsub("c(","{{",arrcol,fixed=T),
         arrcol = gsub(")","}}",arrcol,fixed=T))
```

#### remove brackets

```
df$arrcol = gsub(fixed=T, "{", "", df$arrcol)
df$arrcol = gsub(fixed=T, "}", "", df$arrcol)
```

#### convert to numeric list

```
# Attempt 1: 
df$arrcol = as.numeric(df$arrcol)
# Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

# Attempt 2:
df$arrcol = lapply(df$arrcol, 
                   function(x) strsplit(x, ",", fixed=T))
# no error, but now the data appears to be stored as a list of character lists: 
# arrcol[1]: list(c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5",...

# Attempt 3:
df$arrcol = lapply(df$arrcol, 
                   function(x) as.numeric(
                     unlist(
                       strsplit(x, ",", fixed=T))
                   )
)
# this one seems to work
```

Comment: there is an issue filed with the RPostgreSQL package repository but I know outside linking is discouraged: https://github.com/codeinthehole/rpostgresql/issues/5

Answer (score 1):

My own best answer:

```
df$numcol = gsub(fixed=T, "{", "", df$arrcol)
df$numcol = gsub(fixed=T, "}", "", df$numcol)

df$numcol <- lapply(df$numcol, 
                    function(x) as.numeric(
                      unlist(
                        strsplit(x = x, split = ",", fixed=T)
                      )
                    )
)
```

[updated to perform all steps in one go]

```
df$numcol <- lapply(df$arrcol, 
                    function(x) as.numeric(
                      unlist(
                        strsplit(
                          x = gsub("[{]|[}]", "", x), 
                          split = ",", fixed=T))))
```

or, equivalently:

```
df$numcol <- lapply(df$arrcol, 
                    function(x) as.numeric(
                      strsplit(
                          x = gsub("[{]|[}]", "", x), 
                          split = ",", fixed=T)[[1]]
                    )
)
```

Alternatively, (as long as each of the arrays has the same length) you could use this trick ([Splitting a dataframe string column into multiple different columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18641951/splitting-a-dataframe-string-column-into-multiple-different-columns)) to parse the string into separate columns.  Note that `read.table` is clever enough to recognize each of the new variables as integers.

```
newdf = read.table(text = df$arrcol, header = F, sep = ",")
```

Additionally, you can easily append those as their own columns onto the original `data.frame`:

```
df = cbind(df, newdf)
```

or, knowing how many new columns will be produced:

```
df[,3:101] <- read.table(text = gsub("[{]|[}]", "", df$arrcol), 
                         header = F, sep = ",")
```