# Splitting one column into multiple columns based on a marker character

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame with two columns as:

```
**+-----+-------+
|  V1 |  V2     |
+-----+---------+
|  1  | a,b,c   |
|  2  | a,c     |
|  3  | b,d     |
|  4  | e       |
|  .  | .       |
+-----+-------+**
```

I want to split the second column to multiple columns based on a marker character inside the second column. I want the output to be like following.

```
**+-----+-------------+
|  V1 |  V2 | V3 | V4 |
+-----+---------------+
|  1  |  a  | b  | c  |
|  2  |  a  | c  | NA |
|  3  |  b  | d  | NA |
|  4  |  e  | NA | NA |
|  .  |  .  | .  | .  |
+-----+-------------+**
```

This is a generalization of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18641951/splitting-a-dataframe-string-column-into-multiple-different-columns) but with unbalanced sizes. For example the following example:

```
myVec <- c("F.US.CLE.V13", "F.US.CA6.U13", "F.US.CA6.U13","F.US.CA6", "F.US", "F")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Or you can try this package `splitstackshape`

```
cSplit(dat, 2, drop = TRUE,sep=',')


   V1 V2_1 V2_2 V2_3
1:  1    a    b   c
2:  2    a    c   NA
3:  3    b    d   NA
4:  4    e    NA  NA
```

Comment: I think this is the simplest. Thanks all for quick responses.

Comment: @Rotail Glad it help , nice day

Answer (score 4):

You can use `tidyr` and its `separate` function

```r
library(tidyr)
DF <- data.frame(V1 = 1:4, V2 = c("a,b,c", "a,c", "b,d","e"))
separate(DF, V2, into = c("V2", "V3", "V4"))
#> Warning: Too few values at 3 locations: 2, 3, 4
#>   V1 V2   V3   V4
#> 1  1  a    b    c
#> 2  2  a    c <NA>
#> 3  3  b    d <NA>
#> 4  4  e <NA> <NA>
```

If you want you can suppress the warning with `fill` argument

```r
separate(DF, V2, into = c("V2", "V3", "V4"), fill = "right")
#>   V1 V2   V3   V4
#> 1  1  a    b    c
#> 2  2  a    c <NA>
#> 3  3  b    d <NA>
#> 4  4  e <NA> <NA>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `data.table::tstrsplit`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, c(list(V1), tstrsplit(V2, ","))]

#   V1 V2 V3 V4
#1:  1  a  b  c
#2:  2  a  c NA
#3:  3  b  d NA
#4:  4  e NA NA
```

---

```
myVec
#[1] "F.US.CLE.V13" "F.US.CA6.U13" "F.US.CA6.U13" "F.US.CA6"     "F.US"        
#[6] "F"           

as.data.table(tstrsplit(myVec, '\\.'))

#   V1 V2  V3  V4
#1:  F US CLE V13
#2:  F US CA6 U13
#3:  F US CA6 U13
#4:  F US CA6  NA
#5:  F US  NA  NA
#6:  F NA  NA  NA
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dplyr` and `tidyr`. `dt2` is the final output. Notice that `separate` from `tidyr` will work, but you need to know how many columns you are going to create beforehand. This solution does not need that.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# Example data frame
dt <- data_frame(V1 = 1:4,
             V2 = c("a,b,c", "a,c", "b,d", "e"))

# Process the data
dt2 <- dt %>%
  separate_rows(V2) %>%
  rename(Value = V2) %>%
  group_by(V1) %>%
  mutate(Col = paste0("V", 1:n() + 1)) %>%
  spread(Col, Value)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are OK writing two lines of code, why not this approach:
1) split the strings according to the special character (comma)
2) find the max number of elements you exploded
3) prepare a table with the available elements, add NA when needed
4) wrap up and return your data frame.

```
df <- cbind(1:5, c("a", "a,b,v", "a,c", "d,f,f", "ddd"))
split.strings <- strsplit(df[,2], ",")
#
# get the max length
max.elems <- max(sapply(split.strings, length))
#
# wrap
new.data <- sapply(1:max.elems, (function(i){
  sapply(1:nrow(df), (function(rw){
    if (length(split.strings[[rw]]) >= i) {
      split.strings[[rw]][i]
    } else {
      NA
    }
  }))  
}))
#
# bind to identifier
final.df <- data.frame(id = df[,1], 
                       new.data,
                       stringsAsFactors = F)
final.df
```